# using hammerjs, how can I swipe left/right and display the next document in a collection (MeteorJS)

Tags: meteor, hammer.js

What I'm trying to do sounds simple. Basically on my mobile app I want to be able to swipe to view the next document of a collection using chriswessels:hammer.
Right now when I swipe nothing happens however the code is there to allow me to swipe.

```
Template.auctionDetails.gestures({

  'swipeleft #ascensorBuilding': function (event, template) {
    alert('swipe left');
    event.preventDefault();
    return AuctionDeals.find(_id).next();

  },

  'swiperight #ascensorBuilding': function (event, template) {
    alert('swipe right');
    event.preventDefault();
    return AuctionDeals.find(_id).next();
  }

});
```

Comment: Hi, did you get solution of your problem? In case you find some workaround please do share.

Answer (score -2):

so, when you swipe left you can swipe right too, you'd better try anther way that can solve you problem. gates maybe can help you ,good luck to you ..

Comment: You are not adressing the question at all.

Comment: What i'm trying do is this, so when you swipe left ..it shows the next document. swipe right shows the document you was just on. vice versa.

A good example would be the groupon mobile app.